# Convergence in localized Sobolev spaces $H^m_{loc}$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces

My question is how to obtain (strong) convergence in Frechet spaces $H^m_{loc}(\Omega)$, $m\ge1$ using the following result found in Lions (Perturbations Singulières dans les Problèmes aux Limites et Contrôle Optimal, p. 121), take m=1 for simplicity:

If

1) $u_\varepsilon\to u$ in $L^2_{loc}(\Omega)$,

2) $\varepsilon^{1/2}u_\varepsilon$ is bounded in $H^1_{loc}(\Omega)$,

3) $-\varepsilon \Delta u_\varepsilon+u_\varepsilon$ is bounded in $H^1_{loc}(\Omega)$.

Then,

(a) $\varepsilon^{1/2}u_\varepsilon$ is bounded in $H^2_{loc}(\Omega)$,

(b) $u_\varepsilon$ is bounded in $H^1_{loc}(\Omega)$.

Moreover, this implies that $u_\varepsilon\to u$ in $H^1_{loc}(\Omega)$.

My problem is with the last assertion, I do see how to get the convergence in $H^1_{loc}(\Omega)$

Comment: Certainly not, as these spaces are infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Are you sure that is what Lions claims? It seems to me something like $u_\epsilon(x) = \epsilon \sin(x/\epsilon)$ should be a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you, good example. Besides, I see that this example does not meet the additional conditions in the Lions result. I did not include them the first time because I thought their role was already done once the boundedness of $u_\epsilon$ in $H^1_{loc}$ was shown.

Answer (score 0):

It is false. If you take $v_n=\frac1{n^{1/2}}\chi_{[0,1/n]}$ and $u_n(x)=\int_0^x v_n(s)\,dx$, you have that $v_n$ is bounded in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with norm $1$ and so $u_n$ is bounded in $H^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ but $u'_n=v_n$ does not converge in the compact set $[0,1]$ since it converges to zero but its $L^2$ norm in $[0,1]$ is $1$.
The sequence in Lions book has several additional properties.

Comment: Good example, I think $n^{1/2}$ should be a multiplier. And you are right, the Lions' result has two additional conditions which I did not include the first time because they are already used to show the boundedness of $u_\varepsilon$ in $H^1_{loc}$. I still do not see how they are used again to obtain the convergence from the boundedness. I'll have to think more and better to find out, but any help is more than welcome. I am modifying the original post to include all the hypotheses.